# error getting while creating hive table

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hql

Before creating the twitter table i added this
ADD JAR hdfs:///user/hive/warehouse/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

I got the following error when create the twitter table in hive:
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return 
code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde:
com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe

Answer (score 0):

Move the Jar from HDFS to Local.
Then try to add JAR in hive terminal
Then try to use the query on Twitter Table

Answer (score 0):

Ideally speaking you can add jars from both Local file system or hdfs, looks like problem could be something else here.

I would recommend to follow below sequence of steps:

- List the file on hdfs to make sure it exists

  ```
  hadoop fs -ls hdfs://namenode_hostname:8020/user/hive/warehouse/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  ```
- Add the jar in the hive using full path like above and verify the
     addition using list jars command in hive cli   Use the serde in

  ```
  hive>list jars;
  ```
- create table statement with proper syntax as show here for example
  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RowFormats&SerDe